# Boost Thread Exception Handling

Tags: multithreading, boost, exception, boost-thread

I'm trying to throw an exception within a thread and allow the calling process to catch it.  However, it seems that this will cause the entire application to crash.  See test code attached never prints either exit statement.

```
1 #include <boost/thread.hpp>
2 #include <iostream>
3
4 void wait(int seconds)
5 {
6       boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(seconds));
7 }
8
9 void thread()
10 {
11       for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
12       {
13           wait(1);
14           std::cout << i << std::endl;
15       }
16       throw;
17 }
18
19 int main()
20 {
21     try
22     {
23         boost::thread t(thread);
24         t.join();
25         std::cout << "Exit normally\n";
26     }
27     catch (...)
28     {
29         std::cout << "Caught Exception\n";
30     }
31 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at boost exception: [Transporting of Exceptions Between Threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_exception_ptr.html). 
This approach has worked well for me.

Comment: This became even easier in C++11 (any exception can be captured in `std::exception_ptr`)

Comment: @Cubbi Thanks for the info, I was unaware of that :)